# ESP 8266 MicroPython getting partial data for POST

Tags: esp8266, watchdog, micropython

I'm trying to set up a simple HTTP web server on ESP8266-01 (1MB flash), which has latest 1.9.3 MicroPython firmware. The purpose is to be able to configure the credentials for the home network, to which the STA interface would ultimately connect.

So the code at high level does this:

- Turns on the AP interface
- Some one would connect to `192.168.0.1/index.html`, which would have a form for username and password. We just need to put admin/admin. Clicking on Submit button should do a POST to `192.168.0.1/configure.html`
- `Configure.html` is a web page with a form, where SSID and password would be input. I hope you can follow more details by looking at the code below

I am facing two problems:

1. The total number of bytes that I receive when `index.html` form is submitted are not complete. I get to around Referrer (that too partial), all a total of around 560 bytes. This is when I do it from mobile browser. Funny thing, it always gets exactly those many bytes. I can share what I get if that's going to help.
2. The watch dog timer sometimes reboots my module. I'm doing most of the suggested changes in my code - using small sleeps. Is there any way in MicroPython on ESP8266, through which I can 'feed' the WDT so that it does not 'time-out' and reboot my module?

The following is my code:

```py
import gc
import network
gc.collect()
import machine
gc.collect()
import ubinascii
gc.collect()
import ujson
gc.collect()
import uos
gc.collect()
import utime
gc.collect()
import socket
gc.collect()
import select
gc.collect()

html = """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> <title>Ouroboros IoT Login</title> </head>
    <body>
        <form action="configure.html" method="POST">
            Username : <input type="text"  name="username"></br>
            Password: <input type="password" name="password" ></br>
                <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
"""

login_fail_html = """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> <title>Ouroboros IoT Login</title> </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Incorrect Credentials!</h2><br>Please login<br>
        <form action="configure.html" method="POST">
            Username : <input type="text"  name="username"></br>
            Password: <input type="password" name="password" ></br>
                <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
"""

# Check if file exists
def fileExists(fileName):
    try:
        uos.stat(fileName)
        print("File " + fileName + " found!")
        return True
    except OSError:
        print("No file " + fileName + " found!")
        return False

# Turns WiFi ON for configuration
def turn_wifi_on():
    # Setup the AP interface
    ap_if = network.WLAN(network.AP_IF)
    ap_if.active(False)
    ap_if.active(True)
    # Get the MACADDRESS - without any spaces
    macaddress = ubinascii.hexlify(ap_if.config('mac'),'').decode()
    ap_if.config(essid="OUB1_"+macaddress, password="12345678")
    #ap_if.config(essid="OUB1_"+macaddress)
    ap_if.ifconfig(('192.168.0.1', '255.255.255.0', '192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.1'))
    # Configure the AP to static IPs

def turn_wifi_off():
    ap_if = network.WLAN(network.AP_IF)
    ap_if.active(False)

# Find out the stored IoT secret content
def get_iot_secret():
    fileName = 'alpha.txt'
    if fileExists(fileName):
        f = open(fileName)
        content_str = f.read()
        f.close()
        return content_str
    else:
        return 'asdasrefwefefergf9rerf3n4r23irn1n32f'

# Find out the stored home network credential if exist
def get_wifi_config():
    fileName = 'wifi.conf'
    if fileExists(fileName):
        f = open(fileName)
        content_str = f.read()
        f.close()
        content = ujson.loads(content_str)
        return content
    else:
        return None

# Set the home network credentials
def save_wifi_config(essid, passphrase):
    f = open('wifi.conf', 'w')
    config = {'essid':essid, 'passphrase':passphrase}
    config_str = ujson.dumps(config)
    f.write(config_str)
    f.close()


# Find out the stored login credentials
def get_login_config():
    fileName = 'login.conf'
    if fileExists(fileName):
        f = open(fileName)
        content_str = f.read()
        f.close()
        content = ujson.loads(content_str)
        return content
    else:
        # No file exists so far, so use the admin/admin credentials
        return {'user':'admin','password':'admin'}

# Set the login credentials
def save_login_config(user, password):
    f = open('login.conf', 'w')
    config = {'user':user, 'password':password}
    config_str = ujson.dumps(config)
    f.write(config_str)
    f.close()

def turn_gpio_on(device_num):
    # Device Num to Pin Mapping
    if device_num == 0:
        pin_num = 0
    elif device_num == 1:
        pin_num = 2
    # Check Pin
    pin = machine.Pin(pin_num) 
    if pin.value() == 0:
        pin.on()
    # else it is already at HIGH state, nothing to do

def turn_gpio_off(device_num):
    # Device Num to Pin Mapping
    if device_num == 0:
        pin_num = 0
    elif device_num == 1:
        pin_num = 2
    # Check Pin
    pin = machine.Pin(pin_num) 
    if pin.value() == 1:
        pin.off()
    # else it is already at LOW state, nothing to do

def init_pin(device_num):
    # Device Num to Pin Mapping
    if device_num == 0:
        pin_num = 0
    elif device_num == 1:
        pin_num = 2
    #open GPIO0 in output mode & turn it off by default
    pin = machine.Pin(pin_num, machine.Pin.OUT) 
    # Turn off both GPIO initially
    turn_gpio_off(device_num)

# Find out the post parameters in a dictionary
def get_post_params(req):
    print("Inside GET POST PARAMS : req = " + req)
    post_params = req.split('\r\n')[-1:][0]
    # Check if the post body contains the necessary fields
    # Split the post_params by &
    # params : ['username=', 'password=', 'method=POST', 'url=http%3A%2F%2Ftwig-me.com%2Fv1%2Fusergroups%2FWKMUYXELA9LCC', 'jsondata=', 'submit=submit']
    print("post_params : " + post_params)
    params = post_params.split('&')
    print("Params")
    print(params)
    # Initialize the key value pair dict
    post_dict = {}
    # Iterate on each param
    for param in params:
        # Each param would be like 'method=POST', etc
        key_val = param.split('=')
        print("Key Val :")
        print(key_val)
        key = key_val[0]
        val = key_val[1]
        # Update post_dict
        post_dict[key] = val
    return post_dict

# This web server takes care of the WiFi configuration
# max_run_sec 
def web_server(max_run_sec = None):
    # Turn wifi interface ON
    turn_wifi_on()
    # Create server socket
    addr = socket.getaddrinfo('0.0.0.0', 80)[0][-1]
    s = socket.socket()
    # TODO : If both the wifi and sta are operating simultaneously, then bind only to WiFi
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind(addr)
    s.listen(1)
    # s.settimeout(1)

    poller = select.poll()
    poller.register(s, select.POLLIN)

    # Get the current time since epoch
    startTimeEpoch = utime.time()

    while True:
        events = poller.poll(200)  # time in milliseconds
        if events:
            try:
                gc.collect()
                res = s.accept()
                client_s = res[0]
                client_addr = res[1]
                req = ''
                #while True:
                #   data = client_s.recv(200)
                #   if data:
                #       req += str(data, 'utf8')
                #   else:
                #       break
                #   utime.sleep_ms(50)
                req = client_s.recv(4096)
                req = req.decode()
                print(req)
                req = str(req)
                # Came here means that there has been some connection!
                # Reset the start time epoch in such a case:
                startTimeEpoch = utime.time()
                # Check route now
                if req.find('configure.html') != -1:
                    print("Got configure request!\r\n")
                    # Check if the username and password are correct, if not, configure:
                    login_config = get_login_config()
                    username = login_config['user']
                    pwd = login_config['password']
                    print("Username : " + username + ", pwd : " + pwd)
                    # Find the POST PARAMETERS sent
                    # There would be just one entry in the array, so get the 0th index directly
                    # post_params : 'username=&password=&method=POST&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftwig-me.com%2Fv1%2Fusergroups%2FWKMUYXELA9LCC&jsondata=&submit=submit'
                    print("Came here A")
                    post_dict = get_post_params(req)

                    # Now check if the post_dict has the key and value for username and password as needed?
                    username_post = post_dict['username']
                    password_post = post_dict['password']

                    print("Came here B")

                    # Check if the password is same as expected
                    if (username_post == username) and (password_post == pwd):
                        hidden_input = '<input type="hidden" name="username" value="' + username + '"><input type="hidden" name="passphrase" value="' + pwd + '">'
                        # Send the login username and password inside the hidden input field
                        configure_html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head> <title>Ouroboros IoT WiFi Configuration Page</title> </head><body><form action=\"configure_wifi.html\" method=\"POST\">WiFi SSID : <input type=\"text\"  name=\"essid\"></br>WiFi Password: <input type=\"password\" name=\"passphrase\" ></br>" + hidden_input + "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"submit\" name=\"submit\"></form></body></html>"
                        # TODO : Also show link to webpage, where from we can change the login credentials
                        client_s.send(configure_html)   
                    else:
                        client_s.send(login_fail_html)
                elif req.find('configure_wifi.html') != -1:
                    # Check if the username and password are correct, if not, configure:
                    login_config = get_login_config()
                    username = login_config['user']
                    pwd = login_config['password']
                    # Get post parameters
                    post_dict = get_post_params(req)
                    # Now check if the post_dict has the key and value for username and password as needed?
                    username_post = post_dict['username']
                    password_post = post_dict['password']

                    # Check if the password is same as expected
                    if (username_post == username) and (password_post == pwd):
                        # Do some sanity check for handling the new wifi ssid and password
                        new_wifi_ssid = post_dict['essid']
                        new_wifi_passphrase = post_dict['passphrase']
                        # Set the wifi credentials
                        save_wifi_config(new_wifi_ssid, new_wifi_passphrase)
                        client_s.send('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head> <title>Ouroboros IoT WiFi Configuration Success</title> </head><body>Configuration successful!<br>Device would go into reboot now!</body></html>')
                        # Reboot device now
                        machine.reset()
                    else:
                        client_s.send(login_fail_html)
                elif req.find('index.html') != -1:
                    print("Got index.html request!\r\n")
                    client_s.send(html)
                else :
                    # Do nothing
                    print("Invalid request received! Show the login page again!\r\n")
                    client_s.send(html)

                client_s.close()
                machine.idle()
            except OSError:
                # Got no request and it timedout!
                print("Timed-out, no request received!\r\n")
            except Exception as e:
                print("Got some exception\r\n")
                print(str(e))
            finally:
                if max_run_sec is not None:
                    elapsedTime = utime.time() - startTimeEpoch
                    if elapsedTime >  max_run_sec:
                        # Max run time of web server has elapsed, time to exit this mode!
                        break
        utime.sleep_ms()
        machine.idle()

    # When while loop ends!
    s.close()
    # Turn wifi interface OFF
    turn_wifi_off()

# Starts a thread which runs the web server to handle WiFi
def start_web_server(max_run_sec = None):
    # start_new_thread(web_server, (max_run_sec))
    web_server(max_run_sec)



############# MAIN ##########################
# Initialize two pins to INPUT and OFF by default
init_pin(0)
init_pin(1)
#turn_wifi_off()

# Check if the home wifi network has been setup
# Check if home wifi config is valid, if so, connect to it
# If home wifi is not configured, then use the Web server all the time. 
if get_wifi_config() is None:
    # Came here means the wifi is not configured
    # Start the web server
    print("Starting web server")
    start_web_server()
```

## EDIT 1:

I'm able to setup WDT and feed it. So no more WDT reboots. However, POST issue is still there:

FYI, the following is the response:

```
POST /configure.html HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.1
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 43
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: http://192.168.0.1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; Redmi Note 3 Build/LMY47V) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.123 Mobile Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://192.168.0.1/index.html
Accept-Encoding: g
```

As could be seen, the packet received is partial, the Content-Length header says 43 byte payload. But its not received. When using "nc", and running server locally, the packet received is follows:

```
POST /configure.html HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.1
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 43
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Origin: null
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/65.0.3325.181 Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8

username=admin&password=admin&submit=submit
```

Here, the 43 byte length payload could be easily seen.

So my question is, is the almost 800 byte payload too much to handle for ESP8266? Is there anything that could be done to remove the unnecessary headers that browser is sending? Any way to get all the data if its fragmented?

Comment: The watchdog timer is [documented here](http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/esp8266/library/machine.WDT.html). Assuming that allows you to fix your watchdog problem, can I suggest you edit your question and its title to focus on the web form issue? That might attract better answers.

Comment: I don't think that documentation (despite the fact that it lives in the esp8266 tree) is actually correct.  I believe those docs actually reflect the behavior of the WDT module on the PyBoard, but not on esp8266 devices (if you have micropython on an esp8266 handy, you'll note that the WDT constructor does not accept keyword arguments).

Comment: @ouroboros Do you happen to know where in your code the watchdog reboots are happening?

Comment: @larsks how do I debug I micro python where the reboot happened? I can put prints to do basic debugging. Help me out here on ways to debug

Comment: @nekomatic I understand now WDT class should instantiated by passing no parameters . But what is the default Timeout for wdt? This will be important since I will need to feed periodically at intervals less than that default time out

Comment: @larsks oops, [looks like you're right](https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=3410&p=22842). It sounds like the OP needs to confirm that it really is a watchdog problem first though?

Comment: That probably means that there really are two separate questions here...

Comment: @nekomatic I'll post it as two questions, but do you think you could answer one of those?

Comment: I see you've fixed the watchdog issue and edited the title. I can't help with the HTTP problem, sorry :-(

Comment: I fixed (workaround really) by reading each 200 ms for couple seconds. I could have also read until I got Content-Length, and then continue until I encountered \r\n\r\n at which point I needed to read another 'content length' bytes

Comment: have you considered using [picoweb](https://github.com/pfalcon/picoweb) as an alternative web server and to get around the post issue?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem, my configuration is slightly different though.

I import my html from `html_files.py` as shown below.

```
cred_prompt = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ESP8266 connection</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>
            Enter the UID and Password to connect to WiFi
        </h2>
        <form action="/post">
            uid: <input type="text" name="uid">
            password: <input type="text" name="password">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form><br>
    </body>
</html>
"""
```

This is the function I use to get the credentials. I later save them into a file (Successive boots will use them)

```
def get_new_creds():
    sta_if.disconnect()
    print("Setting up webpage to get new credentials")
    addr = socket.getaddrinfo('0.0.0.0', 80)[0][-1]
    soc = socket.socket()
    soc.bind(addr)
    soc.listen(5)
    print("Listening on", addr)
    while True:
        client, addr = soc.accept()
        print("Client connected from", addr)
        request = client.recv(1024)
        request = request.decode().split()
        uid, pwd = '', ''
        if 'uid' in request[1]:
            uid = request[1].split('&')[0].split('=')[1]
            pwd = request[1].split('&')[1].split('=')[1]
            write_new_creds(uid, pwd)
            connect_to_wifi()
            print("The UID is", uid, "and the Password is", pwd)
            client.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-type: text/html\r\n\r\n')
            client.send(html_files.connection_response.format(sta_if.ifconfig()[0]))
            return uid, pwd
        print(request)
        client.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-type: text/html\r\n\r\n')
        client.send(html_files.cred_prompt)
        client.close()
```

This is the whole [boot.py](https://github.com/PrajwalShenoy/home_automation/blob/master/ESP8266/boot.py) code if that helps.